# How to not lose an oversized ring?

Tags: clothing, jewelry

My girlfriend's fingers are becoming slightly thinner with time. Her ring is now a bit too big for her finger. She tried to switch from one finger to another. The two thumbs are too big (and it would look kinda ugly on the thumb) and the 8 other fingers are too small. The ring cannot be easily resized down further more due to its design and as it is not a very fancy ring, we don't feel like paying too much (or even anything!) to make the necessary modifications. Its value is sentimental.

How can we make sure the ring doesn't get lost?

We thought about an elastic to make sure it doesn't move but it is ugly. We thought about adding stuff in the interior of the ring to resize the internal part of the ring but couldn't find something that worked fine. Do you have a trick?

Answer (score 9):

She could hang it from a necklace and avoid the fitting thing altogether.

Answer (score 8):

Even if a jeweler couldn't make the ring smaller, the jeweler could most likely add a thin coating of a similar metal to the inside of the ring, making the hole smaller.

Answer (score 8):

She could try wearing a second ring on the same finger; this second ring must fit more snugly, and she has to wear it "above" the old one (i.e. further toward the tip of the finger). The new ring should then block the original.
Make sure the new ring doesn't fit through the hole of the original ring...

Comment: SO SIMPLE and cool! Upvote.

Answer (score 7):

1. Attach a **ring wrap** to the underside of your ring. A ring wrap is a malleable metal band that wraps around the band of your ring to tighten the ring size. Simply place the wrap around the band and secure it using a set of needle-nose pliers.

**[How to make your own ring wrap?](http://www.craftsy.com/blog/2014/05/basic-wire-wrapping-how-to-make-a-wrap-ring/)**

[image]

2. You can try using **ring guards**.

[image]

### [image]

3. **Ring Snuggies** which you can find on Amazon.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Not really a hack because you have to buy them, but get a ring clip (also known as ring guards, ring sizers, ring adjusters) - they sell 'em on Ebay and other places; they just clip inside the ring and make it smaller. Amazon sells something called ring snuggies, they're just a plastic tube you pop over the underside of the ring, not sure how effective they are.

Answer (score 2):

What about using hot glue on the inside of the ring as a filler. It would make the ring smaller, and is removable and sort of adjustable (using a knife or other tools or limited heat sources).

NB! I have not tried this my self, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Back in the day, we would wrap yarn around the bottom part of the ring in lieu of a ring guard.